# How to put a long instruction into the Terminal?

Tags: command-line

Edit: I'm attempting to follow an answer given to a question. This results in a specific program installed in ubuntu 15.04.

I did not intend to erase what I asked. I'm not clear so I'll write the info to paper and type it in.

Thanks anyways.

Comment: Please make it more clear. Which instruction are you trying to paste into terminal and what is the problem?

Comment: You should copy/ paste that 'long instruction'.

Answer (score 2):

You can use backslash '\' to break a long lone of commands into several lines, for example,

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` is equvalent to

```
sudo apt-get update \
&& sudo apt-get \
upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it into a file, save, make file executable with filename as argument

```
chmod 755 filename
```

Run as

```
./fileName
```

That's called a script